# Issues with ajax and JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I got this problem where my JS-functions won't work/run after i rebuild my HTML page with some new values from my XML-file. To not make this post too long i gathered the HTML/CSS in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qua1ity/g91xpfhx/ (I'ts not fully functional since i don't know how to add xml/ajax stuff to jsfiddle)

Basically, there is an image and a checkbox, when the checkbox is checked then the image gets the class "markedImg" which have a opacity value of 1. This doesn't work when i try to rebuild the html with values from an XML file.

I do the request like this:

```
function doRequest(target) {
    if (XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (ActiveXObject) {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    request.open("GET", target, true);
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
            createHTML(request.responseXML);
        }
    };
}
```

Sending "target" parameter from an addeventlistener

```
categoryMenu.addEventListener("change", function () {
    if (categoryMenu.value === "Flower") {
        doRequest("categories/imgcat0.xml");
    }
    if (categoryMenu.value === "Buttefly") {
        doRequest("categories/imgcat1.xml");
    }
});
```

And then i run the function "createHTML", which rebuilds the html using the values from XML files

```
function createHTML (XMLcode) {
var imgURL = XMLcode.getElementsByTagName("image");
var title = XMLcode.querySelector("title");
var html = "";
imgForm.innerHTML = "";

html += '<h3>' + title.firstChild.data + '</h3>';

for (var i = 0; i < imgURL.length; i++) {
    html += '<div class="outerBox">';
    html += '<label><input type="checkbox" align="middle"><img src="' + imgURL[i].children[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '" alt="img 1" class="unmarkedImg"></label>';
    html += '<div class="innerBox">';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
}
imgForm.innerHTML = html;
}
```

And so far everything works, but when i add the function to add the "markedImg" class, it doesn't run on the newly created HTML elements. Nothing happens with this function basically. The function itself works, which you can see in the jsfiddle example, but it's after you change the category and the "doRequest" functions runs that it doesn't work.

```
checks.forEach(function (checkbox, index) {
checkbox.onchange = function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        unmarkedImg[index].classList.add("markedImg");
    } else {
        unmarkedImg[index].classList.remove("markedImg");
    }
};
});
```

The XML is very simple, just a title and source to the images:

```
<imagecategory>
    <title>Butterfly</title>
    <image>
        <url>http://i.imgur.com/LY1Mq8k.jpg</url>
    </image>
</imagecategory>
```

Sorry if the post got a bit long.. Hopefully this makes sense to someone.
Thanks!

Comment: It appears your assets doesn't exist on the server... http://imgur.com/wUQ3GX7

Comment: the AJAX stuff doesn't work on jsfiddle, however the requests are fully working on my client.

Comment: Ah okay, after looking at this again. Plus I spotted the Notice "This question already has an answer here:" You need to be using event delegation to allow for events to work on new elements that are added to the dom.